# joomla search module - show results on separate page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have created a search module which uses AJAX to display the results without refreshing the page. However my client wants it to be displayed the same way the search module shows data. I cannot use the default search module because I search data from my own tables in the database.

So my question is: How can I show the search results on a new separate page?

Comment: Create a new layout in your component and render that layout for this search result.

Comment: thanks for the answer; however, i dont have a component, i have only a module

Comment: then your module render inside the component layout.It using ajax then you can solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vojtech 
Just write a search plugin and simple module to submit data to the joomla search component.